# Pyspark action not executed because of an PicklingError

Tags: neo4j, pyspark

I want the "execute" method to be executed so to avoid the lazy evaluation of Spark I wanted to do an action (saveAsTextFile) as in the code :

```
def execute(line1):
    line = line1.split(',')    
    print('Hi')
    session = driver.session()
    #vérifions si les noeuds n'existent pas encore et si oui créons les
    session.run("MERGE (n:Person {Tel: {v1} }) MERGE (m:Person {Tel: {v5}}) CREATE (n)-[:EMIT]->(c:Call {location:{v2}, start:{v3}, duration:{v4}})-[:RECEIVE]->(m) ", {'v1':line[0], 'v2':line[1], 'v3':line[3], 'v4':line[4], 'v5':line[5]})    
    session.close()
    return line

def toCSVLine(data):
    return ','.join(str(d) for d in data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext()
    csvData = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1]).cache()    
    csvData.map(execute).map(toCSVLine).saveAsTextFile("doc")
```

But I face the following error :

```
 File "/home/josyanne/Documents/test/./appSpark.py", line 21, in <module>
csvData.map(execute).map(toCSVLine).saveAsTextFile("doc")
 File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1585, in saveAsTextFile
 File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2489, in _jrdd
 File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2422, in _wrap_function
 File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2408, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
 File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 568, in dumps
 File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 918, in dumps
 File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 249, in dump
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object
```

Please may somebody help me fix this error

Comment: If it is not possible to do that operation then how can i do ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver has to be initialized on each node. To do that you should use `mapPartitions` or `foreachPartition` (if you use `saveAsTextFile` only to evaluate things:

```py
def execute(lines):
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver(...)

    for line in lines:
        line = line.split(',')    
        session = driver.session()
        session.run(...)
        session.close()
        yield line

csvData.mapPartitions(execute).map(toCSVLine).saveAsTextFile("doc")
```